# Do vector.emplace_back() and vector.push_back() do the same thing?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

So I was trying to add integers onto the back of my vector and mistakenly thought `push_back()` added the new data onto the front of the vector (aka vector[0]). I did a test in Xcode and tested `push_back()` against `emplace_back()` and got the same results. I thought they were different, but this makes me think that maybe they do the same thing. If this is so, why does vector have the different methods?

Here's my code in case I was doing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std ;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // for push_back
    vector<int> push;
    push.push_back(1);
    push.push_back(2);
    push.push_back(3);
    push.push_back(4);
    push.push_back(5);
    push.push_back(6);
    //display push_back
    for (int i = 0; i < push.size(); i++) {
        cout << "push[" << i  << "]: " << push[i] << endl;
    }
    // distance between the two funcitons
    cout << endl << endl;

    vector<int> emplace;
    emplace.emplace_back(1);
    emplace.emplace_back(2);
    emplace.emplace_back(3);
    emplace.emplace_back(4);
    emplace.emplace_back(5);
    emplace.emplace_back(6);

    //display emplace_back
    for (int i = 0; i < emplace.size(); i++) {
        cout << "emplace[" << i  << "]: " << emplace[i] << endl;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

The return was:

```
push[0]: 1
push[1]: 2
push[2]: 3
push[3]: 4
push[4]: 5
push[5]: 6


emplace[0]: 1
emplace[1]: 2
emplace[2]: 3
emplace[3]: 4
emplace[4]: 5
emplace[5]: 6
```

I know this is a super easy question, but I just want to make sure I am not doing something stupidly wrong and misunderstanding the abilities of the vector class.

Comment: @nawaz That duplicate is not a very good one, it is about a visual studio non-compliance and does not really answer this question.

Comment: `push_back` uses copy/move constructors, `emplace_back` constructs in place.  I believe `emplace_back` is a superset of `push_back`, since you can use copy/move constructors with in-place construction.

Comment: @Aggieboy: Yes, it is. And if it was designed today, we probably would only have `emplace_back`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: That's what it mentions prominently. But one can simply ignore that extra information.

Comment: @Deduplicator I still don't think it really answers this question, perhaps in a tangential way but is that really a duplicate then, sounds pretty lazy to me.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Well, if there's a dupe you like better, don't hesitate to open and re-close.

Comment: @Deduplicator actually I can not find a good duplicate, which means it is probably a good question. I was pretty surprised I expected to find an exact duplicate pretty quickly, otherwise I would have reopened and reclosed already. There may be an exact duplicate out there someplace but If I can't find it after a few minutes then most people searching online for this topic probably can't either.

Comment: The supposed dupe simply can't include a satisfactory answer to this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that `emplace_back` will construct the object in place as opposed to copying or moving, [cppreference section on std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) says:

> which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container. The arguments args... are forwarded to the constructor

This matters in the case of heavy objects. We can see that this was the motivation from the [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2642.pdf) which says:

> The motivation for placement insert is that containers—especially
>   node-based containers—are very useful for the storage of heavy
>   objects. In some environments efficiency is very important,    but
>   there is in general no way to put elements into    containers without
>   copying them. A heavy    object may store its data directly, in which
>   case move semantics will not improve copy performance. Furthermore,
>   when efficiency is critical the    solution cannot depend on compiler
>   optimizations since they are optional and may not occur where
>   they are most needed.    Placement insertion lets us create an element
>   once, in the container where we want it, and never have to move
>   it or copy it. It does so in a simple and direct way by introducing
>   new variadic  functions that take arguments that are passed on to the
>   element’s constructor using variadic templates and perfect forwarding.

We can take an example of were this makes a difference from [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) *Item 42: Consider emplacement instead of insertion*, which has the following example:

```
std::vector<std::string> vs; // container of std::string
vs.push_back("xyzzy"); // add string literal
```

which results in the creation of a temporary as opposed to:

```
vs.emplace_back("xyzzy");
```

which does not.

Comment: `vector::push_back` typically uses placement new also.

Comment: It should perhaps be mentioned (since the OP asked this), that `push_back` and `emplace_back` are exactly the same in the case where we already have an existing object that we want to copy/move into the vector; they are only different when we are simultaneously constructing and pushing, as in your example.